# Cache tags with Ehcache

Tags: java, caching, tags, ehcache

I have 2 functions: first

```
public String doA(Integer userId, String someValue)
```

that I want to cache (taking into account parameters of function), and second

```
public String doB(Integer userId)
```

that should drops cache of function "doA" for current userId.

Does Ehcache support something like [memcached tags](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/) or anything other that can helps me? Or may be anybody knows how I can solve my problem using [ehcache annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/)?

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache annotations should do the trick.

Ehcache annotations let you (in fact, require you) to declare which cache applies to each method.

As I [recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708204/can-i-annotate-a-method-as-cacheable-in-spring) ...